# get sender's id in the canvas page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

I want to get the sender's id in my canvas page using JS SDK.

I have written this code but it doesn't work:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
console.log("one");
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'myAppId', // App ID
        status: true, 
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true});

console.log("two");
FB.api("/me/apprequests", function(response) {
    console.log("1");
    if (response.data && response.data.length > 0) {
        console.log("2");
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            console.log("3");
            if (response.data[i].from) {
                console.log("Sender: " + response.data[i].from);
            }
            else {
                console.log("App request and not a user request, unknown sender");
            }
        }
    }
});

  };
console.log("three");
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all requests then you should query for [/me/apprequests](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/me/?method=GET&path=me/apprequests) which will get you a json array of all app requests pending for the application.
You can then iterate over them and get the sender id.

However, if you want just one request then you should query for `/REQUEST_ID`.
For example, let's say that the id of the request is `xxxx_yyyy` (where xxx is the request id and the yyyy is your user id), then you need: `https://graph.facebook.com/REQUEST_ID`.

---

## Edit

Well, if you want to iterate over all request then ask for all of them to begin with and then iterate over that, instead of issuing an http request per request.
Also, it turns out that the "form" field in the request is only available for "user generated requests" and not for "app generated requests".

Try this code:

```
FB.api("/me/apprequests", function(response) {
    if (response.data && response.data.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            if (response.data[i].from) {
                console.log("Sender: " + response.data[i].from);
            }
            else {
                console.log("App request and not a user request, unknown sender");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to get all requests. I have iterate over them how you can see in my code above, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Just done, but it doesn't work and in firebug I see "document.getElementById("fb-root") is null" :(

Comment: You are loading the sdk wrong. Why don't you just use the code they have in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)?

Comment: excuse me, now I have load sdk correctly but already doesn't work ( I have edited the code above )

Comment: Doesn't work? What exactly do you mean by that? Do you get an error or something?

Comment: I don't get anything, I only see a white page.

Comment: Not even the `console.log` outputs? Try to add more of those at every line of the code and see where it stops.

Comment: I have just added some console.log ( see edited code above please ). This is the output's order: one, three, two, 1.

Comment: Ok, so instead of `console.log("1");` do `console.log(response);` and see what you get back, maybe you're not even authenticated.

Comment: This is the response: code
 2500
 
message
 "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
 
type
 "OAuthException"

Comment: Is there a way to get senders'id without authentication ?

Comment: No, you must authenticate the user first.

Comment: Ok, I will use authentication. Thank you :D